# Efficient ListView in android

Tags: android, android-listview, memory-efficient

What is the best way of constructing a `ListView` that uses the least memory possible? This is important, because I met a few implementations and most of them is lagging when I scroll the `ListView` on low-end devices, but I saw a few apps, where the scroll is very smooth, even on low-end devices. How can it be done? What is the most efficient way from a memory usage point of view to construct such a `ListView`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- recycle your views in `getView()`
- use `ViewHolder` pattern
- use lazy loading if you have a lot of data to fill the list with
- use `Cursor` as underlying data instead of object list built from cursor if your data comes from `database`, you save memory by not creating additional objects.
- see http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html
- see http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use the [ViewHolder](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance_hoder) pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this code](http://animations.typepad.com/blog/2010/07/android-tutorial-73-efficient-listview-with-two-icons.html) with description to increase the efficiency of lisview.

Keep in mind when you have lots of data to show in listview then at a time do not load all data . First load 2o data then load another when listview reaches at end.

This is also another way to increase the efficiency of listview.