# How do I improve the performance of a listview?

Tags: java, android, listview

When I use images from the internet in a `Listview`, my `Listview` scrolls very slowly.
But in some applications such as Twitter, Google+ and other applications (despite showing images from the internet) there is no problem with scrolling and it is very fast and smooth.

How do I improve the performance of a `Listview` with images?

Comment: See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684520/efficient-listview-in-android , probably this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Must check => [Android - How do I do a lazy load of images in ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3068012/379693)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some ThumbRules which might help you in optimizing listview:

-> Reuse Views by using ConvertView, in

```
`getView(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View convertView, int position, long id)`
```

->. Use Lazy Loading for Loading images from web, see

http://codehenge.net/blog/2011/06/android-development-tutorial-asynchronous-lazy-loading-and-caching-of-listview-images/

->   Also use ViewHolders to improve inflation time.check link:

http://jmanzano.me/efficient-listviews-in-android-viewholder-pattern-2/

Answer (score 0):

Check out this one, [list view performance optimization from Larse Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listsactivity_performance)

You can also use `endless list` or `lazy loading` where you load only some part of data in listview & load other when user reaches bottom of list
[lazy loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667064/android-implementing-endless-list-like-android-market) OR
[Commonsware's adapter for endless loading](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless)

Answer (score 0):

use LoaderImageView in your listview. you can get LoaderImageView code from [here](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/imageview-with-loading-spinner/) http://blog.blundell-apps.com/imageview-with-loading-spinner/

modify the LoaderImageView code to store the drawable downloaded